# SSH with Kerberos Auth not working

Tags: debian, ssh, kerberos

I'm trying to log in my Linux VM with SSH using kerberos authentication.

My Linux VM has successfully joined my AD using realmd / sssd method.

I changed my sshd_config settings to :

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
```

On the client side, Mac OS 10.12, .ssh/config contains :

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

When i ssh my Linux VM with -v, here is the output :

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alex/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to plex [192.168.1.23] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 
0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to plex:22 as 'alex'
debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 2 for mech 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 2 10

debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: Offering GSSAPI proposal: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
SHA256:gLapxwxzqzjnfD7CZhnkEkcVeWRPUeh1XnCwKzV8YMs
debug1: Host 'plex' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alex/.ssh/known_hosts:2 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
The ticket isn't for us

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) 
unknown mech-code 2 for mech 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 2 10

debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 
Password:
```

And then it asks for password...

Am i doing something wrong ?

/etc/sssd/sssd/conf is :

```
[sssd]
domains = home.lan
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh

[domain/home.lan]
ad_domain = home.lan
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

krb5_realm = HOME.LAN
realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
```

Thanx !!

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to successfully check the Domain account information using

```
id username@domain
```

Also, check the output of

```
realm discover domain
```

Note this should show output if your Linux machine is a kerberos member:

```
[root@linuxVM ~]# realm discover domain.dom
domain.dom
  **type: kerberos**
  realm-name: DOMAIN.DOM
  domain-name: domain.dom
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-tools
```

And hope you are trying to login as this:

```
ssh username@domain.dom
```

If kerberos member is not being listed then you can use the following to joint in again:

```
realm join domain.dom -U administrator@domain.dom
```

And then enable SSSD login using the following:

```
authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablemkhomedir --update
```

Restart the realmd and sssd services.

*Note by doing this all of the domain users will be able to login to the Linux server. You may want to deny all and enable group specific login but I will leave that to you.*

```
#Deny login to everyone using below:
realm deny --all

#Permit specific AD Groups:
realm permit -g AD_GROUP_NAME@domain.dom
```